# R Shiny app runs fine in R Studio but looks different when deployed to server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I'm new to the R Shiny app but after a lot of effort, I wrote an app that looks and runs fine when tested using R Studio. It looks like the following (that is how I expect it to look, for example, different tabs appear in the upper panel).

[image]

**But** when I deploy it to the Shiny server, it looks like the following and doesn't work. It also doesn't show me any error. Could someone please tell me why this is happening?

[image]

Maybe I'm missing something. Here's the code if you want to take a look: https://github.com/nabil-awan/PTE_Shiny_app

Comment: Just an update: sometimes it shows up in the right format when run for the first time but soon turns into the unwanted format after a reload. But that doesn't happen all the time. What am I missing here?

Comment: First, I'd check the Shiny logs on the server (`/var/log/shiny-server/` or whatever is in the configuration file).  Then I'd run `sessionInfo()` in the two environments and looking for any differences in package versions, R version and OS.  Update any packages not on the latest versions.  Next, I'd check by running both in the same browser - you can click the Open in Browser button at the top of your local version.

Comment: Thanks, updating R and then using the latest version of R in R Studio solved the problem.